# Error handling with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping various webpages using BeautifulSoup, however for the same URL I often get inconsistent results. I believe it is because I'm scraping the same webpage quite often. How do I make sure that the "soup" I'm getting is consistent if I run the same command several times? Is there a nice way to handle this?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

if len(soup.find_all("var","model")) == 0:
   print "test"  # Inconsistent for the same URL if run several times in a row
```

EDIT : Looping this : len(soup.find_all("var","model")), gives me 2 different results ( 0 and 2 ) over time , in a random fashion . That's what I meant by inconsistent, do you guys have tips on where I could be mistaking ?

Comment: what's the inconsistency about? you want to know about error handeling, yet where's the error you are getting?

Comment: the error is that the data is inconsistent, trying to find a why to make sure I always get the same result, it's a static page

Comment: based on what you provided, it seems that the url doesn't always contain a VAR or MODEL tag... i guess you have to provide something more, like the page code, some stacktrace, some errors etc...

Comment: have you manually checked the html?

Answer (score 1):

Either the page isn't really static, or there is an issue causing the page to load only partially in the soup variable. Add a row at the bottom that shows the full size of the tree loaded into soup (Not sure if len() work or suffice). This way you will know if the cause is in the source, or in the BeautifulSoup code.

Comment: I've looped this : len(soup.find_all("var","model")) and it gives me 2 different results over time in a random frequency .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out it wasn`t beautiful soup, I've fetched the same url several time and wrote the html out, turns out there are small differences each time . The page is not really static